# Finding the value of a linear combination out of a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \mathbf x=\mathbf b$ be a system of linear equations with $e$ equations and $n$ unknowns $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, s.t. $e<n$.
Since there are fewer equations than unknowns, we cannot find the individual values of the unknowns.
But, how can I find out if it is possible to compute the value of a linear combination of the unknown, i.e., $\alpha_1 x_1+\cdots+\alpha_n x_n$? What are the necessary and sufficient conditions? What is the systematic way to find such a linear combination?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you represent your system of linear equations as an augmented matrix and then by using elementary row operations, you reduce it to row echelon form. One such algorithm is the Gaussian elimination. The explanation of the algorithm can be found easily on the net.